# Creating a website with IDE tools and testing on a web server

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-services, tomcat

I am trying to create a website for my personal use. For the record, I am a programmer, but with experience in languages such as C/C++ and Java. I do have knowledge however in HTML, CSS, and a bit of javascript.

However, I don't know where to start on writing code to build my website. I am able to write some HTML code in a text editor (say gedit for example), save the file in .html format, and open it with an internet browser. This way seems very tedious because I have to create a different file for every page within the website (for example, if I'm on the home page, and want to access the "contacts" page of the website, I simply create a contacts.html file).

I am not sure if this is the "best" way to go about this. I'm more of a low-level programmer, so I've used tools such as Visual Studio and Eclipse to facilitate compiling and running of Java applications for example, and I'm looking for something similar to build a website.

What I'm asking for and want to know about really is the following:

1- Is there an IDE tool (such as Eclipse) where I can code my website (using HTML and CSS Bootstrap for example)?

2- Am I able to use a web server, such as Tomcat, to deploy my web application to "play around" with my website (i.e, clicking through the different links within the pages)?

This might be a broad question, but if something is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth checking out the JetBrains IDEs (WebStorm which also has JScript integration).

I'm not sure what you mean by question 2. Are you just trying to run the HTML/CSS webpages?

Comment: Yes, I'm just looking for a way to run the webpage.

Comment: You can host your website online, these places usually offer a free year if you look around.

Otherwise, I'm not sure what's wrong with opening the file using a browser. Is there something specific you're after?

Comment: I'm not looking for anything specific, and I have no issue with simply opening the files using a browser, but I was simply wondering if there was a tool that could help with that. Basically, an equivalent IDE tool used for compiling and running Java applications for example, but for HTML code (if that makes sense).

Comment: Your best bet in that case would be either a JetBrains IDE or Adobe Dreamweaver which allows you to code and see the results directly in the same screen.

Again, you can grab free trials for both and see which you prefer.

Comment: Ok this helps a lot thank you! I'll look at both and see what I can do with them.